# How does Google Cloud Platform's Compute Engine handle https automaitcally?

Tags: apache2, ssl, cloud, https

I setup a UAT site for a client on Google Cloud Platform's Compute Engine with Ubuntu 23.10 and allowed HTTP and HTTPS firewall. DNS is at Cloudflare, using the free plan.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.co.in
    ServerAlias mydomain.co.in 
    ServerAdmin info@mydomain.co.in
    DocumentRoot /home/info/mydomain
    <Directory "/home/info/mydomain">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
    </Directory>    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.co.in
    ServerAlias mydomain.co.in 
    ServerAdmin info@mydomain.co.in
    DocumentRoot /home/info/mydomain
    <Directory "/home/info/mydomain">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But somehow the site is working with https. I didn't do anything related to pem files, certbots, etc.

Yes, https is loading normally without showing a warning even. How is this possible?

Oddly, the certificate is showing for the root domain and not the subdomain that I had configured the server for:

[image: Certificate]

Comment: This is a GCP problem, and can't be answered without knowing how you're allowing ingress into the instance. For all we know, the client might have a load balancer or something which is handling the TLS termination.

Comment: Client has 0 knowledge of GCP and Im totally new to it creating only the compute engine allowing HTTP and HTTPS and no load balancer - but I did enable static IP as an addon.

Comment: Both of you being new to it doesn't exclude some other contractor having setup stuff for them before.

Comment: I created this google cloud account and I created the VM here. So there's no way a 3d person could've setup SSL.

Comment: Then where is the DNS configured? Are you actually hitting this server directly when accessing this domain?

Comment: DNS is at cloudflare. I doubt client paid anything to Cloudflare - using the free plan.

Comment: What does the payment plan have to do with it? Cloudflare offers free certificates and TLS termination.

Comment: The Apache VirtualHost configuration block for HTTPS is not complete, therefore Apache is not serving clients on HTTPS. Google Cloud Compute Engine does not provide HTTPS (SSL certificates). You must have some other proxy sitting in front of Apache or you are not actually using Apache.

Comment: Oddly, the certificate is showing for the root domain and not the subdomain that I had configured the server for - https://imgur.com/pYjVfuj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the site's SSL/TLS encryption mode set to Flexible in Cloudflare. With this option, the https is not handled by Google Cloud Platform, but by Cloudflare.

Quote from the official [Cloudflare Flexible - SSL/TLS encryption modes](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes/flexible/) docs:

> Setting your encryption mode to Flexible makes your site partially
> secure. Cloudflare allows HTTPS connections between your visitor and
> Cloudflare, but all connections between Cloudflare and your origin are
> made through HTTP. As a result, an SSL certificate is not required on
> your origin.

[image]

Open your account, open the domain and go to *SSL/TLS*. You can check the settings there. It should look like this:

[image: Cloudflare SSL/TLS Settings]

If you are wondering why your certificate is issued by Google Trust Services LLC, check these:

- [I've installed Cloudflare but it turns out to be Google Trust Services SSL](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/ive-installed-cloudflare-but-it-turns-out-to-be-google-trust-services-ssl/412442)
- [Certificate being issued by GoogleTrustServicesLLC](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/certificate-being-issued-by-googletrustservicesllc/385491)